# How insert delay between all test steps in SoapUI?

Tags: testing, delay, soapui

Suppose I have a scenario with 10 steps. It does not matter what steps they are. Is it possible to setup SoapUI to insert delay into all steps? I mean not to insert build-in "Delay" test step after each step but just set something in SoapUI.

I can not use build-in "Delay" step because there are some scripts in test cases and they are linked between steps and after insert build-in "Delay" after each step these link's become broken.

Comment: If the value of delay doesn't vary you can add Thread.sleep(value_of_delay) in your script

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [custom event](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/custom-event-handlers.html): make it of type `submitListener.beforeSubmit` and the body would simply have `Thread.sleep(1000)`.

Note that is a Pro- feature.